# Active Directory to authenticate with an other A.D

Tags: active-directory, authentication

I want to deploy an Active Directory. There are some users of an other A.D. domain that should get access to the computers that will be part of my own A.D. domain. Can I configure this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's called a trust relationship - not the sort of thing a few lines of answer on this site may be able to help you with as they can be quite complex depending on the setup of both ADs but it's more than possible.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Chopper3 this can be very complex. Here is an article on Technet: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727050.aspx
Server 2003
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759554(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether or not these domains are a part of the same forest.  An Active Directory forest consists of one or more domains.  Domains in the same forest have an implicit 2 way trust.  Domains in different forests require a cross forest trust see [How Domain and Forest Trusts Work](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773178(WS.10).aspx)